# How to fetch slugs from server to header in Next.js

Tags: next.js, slug, react-context

I try to fetch data (slugs of categories) from my server and use it inside the header navbar that is reusable in all the site.

1. In `_app` I have the layout which contains the header component:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, appProps, pageProps, router }) {
    return (
        <>
            <SlugContext.Provider value={{ slugs: pageProps.response }}>
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
            </SlugContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    const response = await axios
        .get(`${API}/categories/`)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    const pageProps = await App.getInitialProps({ response, ...ctx });
    return { pageProps: { ...pageProps, response } };
};
```

2. In the header navbar I put the context:

```js
const context = useContext(SlugContext);
```

and inside I have links like:

```js
<NavLink href={`/categories/${context.slugs[0].slug}`} onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
<NavLink href={`/categories/${context.slugs[1].slug}`} onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
```

3. **THE PROBLEM**: When I console log inside the header I can see my slugs. When I click on one link -> it directs me to the slug, like: `http://localhost:3000/categories/slugone`

Bu the following message appears:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
...........
href={`/categories/${context.slugs[0].slug}`}===undefined
```

Why is it undefined with 0, if before he have all the slugs data? It has to be in the context, why does it disappear and how can I handle it?

Comment: Thank for the edit.. u can help me with the question?

Comment: If you console log `pageProps.response` in `MyApp`, is it ever `undefined`? Is the axios request ever returning `undefined`?

Comment: No. The console log in the _app log the data correctly (the slugs). And also pass it correctly the data to Header

Comment: when i first refresh localhost:3000 . and console log inside _app, i get in the console:
console from _app ::::
[{slug:"blabla"},{slug:"blbal2}]
which says that is not undefined...

Comment: after. i console from Header compoennet and get the same log (which pass from the context)

Comment: and when i clicked on one of the buttons that direct me its direct me to localhost:3000/categories/blabla and right after ---> fall with the undefined like i explained in the post

Comment: The only explanation I can see is that the `axios` request in `getInitialProps` is failing on client-side transition somehow, setting `response` to `undefined`. Can you see the `axios` response in your browser's console when clicking a nav link? Make sure no error is being thrown on that request when a client-side transition occurs.

Comment: ok u right. after click a navlink i get from _app 
_app.js:49 !!!!!!!!!pageprops from app undefined
why is happend?

Comment: and i thought that is need to invoke only one time when user first visit the site. and then fetch the data, and then get all the data from the context this is what i tried and need to do, am i right?

Comment: To answer your first question: you'll have to debug that from your side. Check the network tab in dev tools to see why the request might be failing. Regarding your second question: `getInitialProps` will run on the server for the initial page load, but will also run on the client when navigating to a different route.

Comment: im trying to look at network tab but i just see that it failed(filed to fetch response data)... and i dont understand how can it failed if its the same function to get from the server... that success before

Comment: and also i dont understand why its not holding the slugs in the state(in the context that i created)

Comment: The context state is being overwritten by `pageProps.response` which will be `undefined` due to the request failing.

Comment: ok so now this i understand. but how can i check why i get undefined? like i said i just see failed.. and dont understand beacuse is the same func that succedd to fetch data before.

Comment: or the question is how can i fetch the data for the context only one time in the start..

Comment: when i console log inside the MYAPP.getInitialProps,
in the first loaded the site, i see in the console the data.
after click on navlink it failed with undefind and not even print the console log inside the getInitialProps

Comment: also in post man when i trying to get same path ( http://localhost:8000/api/categories ) i get expected result .. all the slugs categories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227056/discussion-between-roei-grinshpan-and-juliomalves).